# Trouble with 'if statements' inside other 'if statements'

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if(clicked == button) {
    button.setIcon(image1);
    if(clicked == button2) {
        button2.setIcon(image2)
        button1.setIcon(image0)
     }
}
```

Basically what I want the code to do, is upon clicking '`button`' it's image will be set to '`image1`' and after that happens(specifically not before) if another button is clicked it will set that button(button2) to '`image2`' and make the first button display '`image0`' it's "idle" image, if you will.

Now if all of this makes sense, I'd like to get an answer of why clicking 'button2' after clicking 'button' doesn't do anything.

YES, I have the action listeners, and everything setup for the JLabels etc, all I need help on is getting the if statement inside of the other if statement to be 'run' after the first if statement, and only if the first '`button`' is clicked.

Comment: You cannot do this in the same click handler. Each click handler acts only on a single user event and immediately returns. Then the user gets to click again and invoke a second handler. You cannot "wait" there for the next event. What you can do is record the fact that the first click has happened (so that the later handler can act upon that "state"). Or maybe add another click handler that was not there before.

Comment: You have applied button 2 click event inside button 1 click event, so it will not execute anytime as it will check for button 1 then clicked will be always button 1 and therefore it will never go inside for button2 and if your clicked will be button 2 then it will not go inside from first if condition so this is not correct logic, to make it possible separate both events and apply flag for it then only it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have applied button 2 click event inside button 1 click event, so it will not execute anytime as it will check for button 1 then clicked will be always button 1 and therefore it will never go inside for button2 and if your clicked will be button 2 then it will not go inside from first if condition so this is not correct logic,

To make it possible separate both events and apply flag for it then only it will work

**check below answer**

```
//Declare one variable at top like below
boolean isButtonClicked = false;

   if(clicked == button) 
   {
       button.setIcon(image1);
       isButtonClicked = true;
   }
   else if(clicked == button2)
   {
      if(isButtonClicked) 
      {
           button2.setIcon(image2);
           button1.setIcon(image0);
           isButtonClicked = false;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare at least one private boolean variable to check whether the first button is clicked.

Then you will use the logical and ( && ) operator to check if the first button was clicked before the other button got clicked.

```
private boolean firstBtnClicked = false;
```

Then you will modify your code as below :

```
if(clicked == button) {
button.setIcon(image1);
firstBtnClicked = true;
}
if(firstBtnClicked == true && clicked == button2) {
    button2.setIcon(image2);
    button1.setIcon(image0);
}
```

I hope this works.